# Could I apply the master theorem if my $N/b$ is $\varphi(N)$?

Tags: master-theorem

Let

$$T(N) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } N = 1\\
T(\varphi(N)) + \lg(\varphi(N))^3 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

where $\varphi(N)$ is Euler's totient function.

Can I somehow express $\varphi(N)$ as $N/b$, so I can apply the Master Theorem and resolve this recurrence?

You may assume $\varphi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)$, if it's easier that way.  You may also assume, if it helps, that $p$, $q$ are safe primes, that is, $p = 2p' + 1$ and $q = 2q' + 1$.  (Assume anything that makes the problem easier.  For instance, you can replace the function $\lg^3(\varphi(N))$ with any other that makes the problem easier, but do so only as a last resort.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not apply the master theorem directly. However, you can play with your expression a bit to get an upper bound on which you can then apply the master theorem.

First, show that $\phi(\phi(n)) < n/2$. This can be done as such:

Let $n = \prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{k_i}$ be the prime factorisation of $n$ ($p_i$ prime, $k_i>0$)

- Suppose $n$ is even. Then $\phi(n) = n\prod_{i=1}^r(1-\frac{1}{p_i}) \leq n(1-\frac{1}{2}) \leq n/2.$ Thus $\phi(\phi(n)) < n/2$.
- Suppose $n$ is odd and $n > 1$. Then $\phi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r (p_i-1)p_i^{k_i-1}$ is even and smaller than $n$. By the previous result $\phi(\phi(n)) < n/2$.

So we get the desired result.

Now suppose $n\geq2$. You can write:
$$T(n) = T(\phi(n))+\log(\phi(n))^3 = T(\phi(\phi(n)))+\log(\phi(\phi(n)))^3 + \log(\phi(n))^3.$$
$$T(n) \leq T(n/2) + 2\log(n)^3.$$

Now you can apply the master theorem here to get:
$$T(n) = O(log(n)^4).$$

Comment: Are you sure the answer is $O(\log^4 n)$?  Looking at Cormen's book, I understood $a = 2$, $b = 2$ and case 1 applies because $2 \log^3 n \in O(n^{(\log_2 2) - e}) = O(n)$, so the answer would be $\Theta(n^{\log_2 2}) = \Theta(n)$.  Where am I wrong?  How did you get the 4th power?

Comment: You have a=1 and not 2, so you can use case 2 of the more precise formulation given here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms). Alternatively, you can just do a prove by induction without using the master theorem, it will yield the same result quite easily.

Comment: Notice also that because we work on an upper bound of $T$ and not the exact formula, we can no longer deduce lower bounds on the complexity via the master theorem, thus we can only get $T(n)=O(\text{something})$ and no longer $T(n)=\Theta(\text{something})$.

Comment: Thanks for the last comment --- I'm really learning things here.  So, I see you're right, and I only see now that I mistyped my recurrence.  I really wanted to write $2T(N)$ for the inductive case, so while you're answer is perfectly correct, I think the answer I'm looking for does fall in case 1 of the Master Theorem given my mistyping here.  I'm not updating the question and I'm marking your answer as the accepted one.  Thank you!

Comment: But do you confirm that if $a = 2$, then case 1 applies and we get $O(n)$ as the answer?

Comment: Oh I see, no worries :) And yep, $O(n)$ for $a=2$ seems right to me.

Comment: But this also means that this is exponential growth in $\lg n$, right?  Because $n$ doubles if we increase it by one bit.  I was expecting a polynomial-time complexity.  I did not expect $T(n)$ to be exponential considering $2T(n) + F(n)$ in the inductive step.  But it does seem to make sense because the upper bound you derived breaks the problem in two halves, but then has to solve two problems of half-size.  That might very well be linear in $n$ and exponential in $\lg n$.  (Sanity-check: I started using $N$ but you went along with $n$, so I switched to $n$ too, but my $N$ is your $n$.)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I just realized that my upper bound doesn't work out that way any more if $a = 2$. In fact, the new upper bound would be $T(n) \leq 4T(n/2) + ...$, which leads to $O(n^2)$. But regarding your point, yes, in the first case of the master theorem growth can be arbitrarily fast in $F(n)$. Try it out with $F(n) = 0$ and you'll get, hum, infinite growth in $F(n)$, whatever that means

Comment: I've got [another recurrence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113080), if you're still in the mood to find upper bounds.

Comment: Why is this equation true?

$$T(n) = T(\phi(n))+\log(\phi(n))^3 = T(\phi(\phi(n)))+\log(\phi(\phi(n)))^3 + \log(\phi(n))^3.$$